# Getting weird value in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Getting exactly correct data in stored procedure. but when i am trying to get that value in C# datatable getting wrong data. not sure why i am getting that.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSurveyStatistic]
    (@SurveyID int,
     @NameOfSubmitter varchar(200),
     @NameOfPrivacyContact varchar(200),
     @HspOrganizationalName varchar(200),
     @HspSiteNumber varchar(200),
     @FromDate datetime,
     @ToDate datetime,
     @weekly bit)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@ToDate IS NOT NULL) 
        SET @ToDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ToDate)

    IF @Weekly = 0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            CAST(CAST(StartedDateTime AS date) AS varchar(10)) Value, 
            COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM
            SubmittedSurveys
        WHERE
            (SurveyID = @SurveyID OR @SurveyID IS NULL)
            AND (StartedDateTime >= @FromDate OR @FromDate IS NULL)
            AND (StartedDateTime <= @ToDate OR @ToDate IS NULL)
            AND (LOWER(ProvidedNameOfSubmitter) LIKE LOWER(@NameOfSubmitter) + '%' 
                 OR @NameOfSubmitter IS NULL OR @NameOfSubmitter = '')
            AND (LOWER(NameOfPrivacyContact) LIKE LOWER(@NameOfPrivacyContact) + '%' 
                 OR @NameOfPrivacyContact IS NULL
                 OR @NameOfPrivacyContact = '')
            AND (LOWER(HspOrganizationalName) LIKE LOWER(@HspOrganizationalName) + '%'  
                 OR @HspOrganizationalName IS NULL
                 OR @HspOrganizationalName = '')
            AND (LOWER(HspSiteNumber) LIKE LOWER(@HspSiteNumber) 
                 OR @HspSiteNumber IS NULL OR @HspSiteNumber = '')
        GROUP BY
            CAST(StartedDateTime AS date)
        ORDER BY 
            1
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT
            CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, StartedDateTime) AS varchar(10)) Value, 
            COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM
            SubmittedSurveys
        WHERE
            (SurveyID = @SurveyID OR @SurveyID IS NULL)
            AND (StartedDateTime >= @FromDate OR @FromDate IS NULL)
            AND (StartedDateTime <= @ToDate OR @ToDate IS NULL)
            AND (LOWER(ProvidedNameOfSubmitter) LIKE LOWER(@NameOfSubmitter) + '%' 
                 OR @NameOfSubmitter IS NULL OR @NameOfSubmitter = '')
            AND (LOWER(NameOfPrivacyContact) LIKE LOWER(@NameOfPrivacyContact) + '%' 
                 OR @NameOfPrivacyContact IS NULL
                 OR @NameOfPrivacyContact = '')
            AND (LOWER(HspOrganizationalName) LIKE LOWER(@HspOrganizationalName) + '%'  
                 OR @HspOrganizationalName IS NULL
                 OR @HspOrganizationalName = '')
            AND (LOWER(HspSiteNumber) LIKE LOWER(@HspSiteNumber) 
                 OR @HspSiteNumber IS NULL OR @HspSiteNumber = '')
        GROUP BY
            CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, StartedDateTime) AS varchar(10))
        ORDER BY 
            1
    END
END
```

and here is the results

[image]

but in front end getting "Value" ="Date" instead of week value

Here is the code of front end

```
public static List<SubmittedSurveys> GetSurveyStatistic(int SubmittedSurveyId, DateTime                 
     StartedDateTime, string NameOfSubmitter, string NameOfPrivacyContact, string 
     HspOrganizationalName, string HspSiteNumber,
     DateTime CompletedDateTime,bool weekly)
{
     try
     {
         DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
         Database _wohcDB = factory.Create("SurveyToolDBEntities");
         // SqlDatabase _wohcDB = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("SurveyToolDBEntities") as 
      SqlDatabase;

         string sqlCommand = "[GetSurveyStatistic]";

         DbCommand dbCommand = _wohcDB.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand);

         _wohcDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@SurveyID", DbType.Int32, SubmittedSurveyId);
         _wohcDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@FromDate", DbType.DateTime, StartedDateTime);
         _wohcDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@ToDate", DbType.DateTime, CompletedDateTime);
         _wohcDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@NameOfSubmitter", DbType.String, NameOfSubmitter);
         _wohcDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@NameOfPrivacyContact", DbType.String, NameOfPrivacyContact);
         _wohcDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@HspOrganizationalName", DbType.String, HspOrganizationalName);
         _wohcDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@HspSiteNumber", DbType.String, HspSiteNumber);
         _wohcDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@weekly", DbType.String, weekly);

         DataSet ds = _wohcDB.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);

         _submittedSurvey = ReportsController.DbConverter.DataTable2List<SubmittedSurveys>(ds.Tables[0]);
         //_submittedSurvey[0].SurveyReports = ReportsController.DbConverter.DataTable2List<Reports>(ds.Tables[1]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string message = ex.Message.ToString();
    }

    return _submittedSurvey;
}
```

Here is the screenshot of front end where I am getting wrong value as a date instead of week

[image]

Can somebody help me to resolve this issue. This is so weird. i also tried to cast in int but getting error that date can not convert into int. I am not sure that why I am getting wrong data in front end and getting right data in backend?

Please help me.

Comment: What is the _exact_ value of `weekly`? **Do not guess**. Why are you using `DbType.String` for a boolean / bit?

Comment: the weekly Value is 53. I am converting weeks into nvarchar(10). thats why i am using string in front end. to get "53" as a string

Comment: I am referring to `_wohcDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@weekly", DbType.String, weekly);`.

Comment: `the weekly Value is 53` **No it isn't**. It has a data type of `bool` (`bool weekly`).

Comment: sorry corrected but getting same value as date

Comment: I will ask again - **what is the value of `weekly`** (the C# boolean)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the else part then it will work fine. with this query it will always go to if statement because of @Weekly =0.

Comment: yeah thats worked in my case. As you said i run else part only removed if else statement. Thank you so much

Comment: This only worked since _you were passing the wrong value of `weekly`_.

Answer (score 2):

Try to Change:

```
   _wohcDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@weekly", DbType.String, weekly);
```

To:

```
   _wohcDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@weekly", DbType.Boolean, weekly);
```